I am adding unit tests using jest for the code which is working perfectly as per the requirement, while running npm test getting getting error
while running npm start the application working perfectly, but running the npm test gets the below error
 TypeError: (0 , _ToastComponent.showToast) is not a function

      20 |         } = error;
      21 |         if (response && msg) {
    > 22 |             showToast(msg, "toast toast-danger", "alert", true, getToastTimeLimit());
         |                      ^
      23 |         } else {
      24 |             showToast("Internal server error!", "toast toast-danger", "alert", true, getToastTimeLimit());
      25 |         }

my jest-setup.js file is
import '@testing-library/jest-dom';
and my package.json is
{
  "name": "test-ui",
  "private": true,
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "vite",
    "test": "jest",
    "build": "vite build",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext js,jsx --report-unused-disable-directives --max-warnings 0",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.18.6",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.25.9",
    "@trimble-oss/modus-icons": "^1.15.0",
    "@trimble-oss/modus-react-components": "^0.36.0-react18",
    "@trimbleinc/modus-react-bootstrap": "^1.2.4",
    "axios": "^1.7.7",
    "date-fns": "^4.1.0",
    "express": "^4.21.1",
    "gulp": "^5.0.0",
    "jwt-decode": "^3.1.2",
    "react": "^18.3.1",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.10.4",
    "react-dom": "^18.3.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.26.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.26.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.26.0",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.8.3",
    "@testing-library/dom": "^9.3.4",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^6.6.3",
    "@testing-library/react": "^14.3.1",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^3.1.0",
    "babel-jest": "^27.5.1",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
    "eslint": "^6.8.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^18.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.20.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.2.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.19.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^1.7.0",
    "jest": "^27.5.1",
    "jest-css-modules-transform": "^4.4.2",
    "vite": "^4.5.5"
  }
}

and my code which shows the error is
import http, { getRefreshToken } from "./httpService";
import { showToast } from "../components/common/ToastComponent";
import { showSpinner } from "../components/common/SpinnerComponent";
import { getToastTimeLimit } from "../properties/properties";
import { loadConfig } from "../utils/util";

export async function getAccessToken(username, password) {
    const { hostName } = await loadConfig();
    try {
        const response = await http.post(`${hostName}/test/test`, { username, password });
        console.log("Login successful :-)");
        return response;
    } catch (error) {
        const {
            response: {
                data: { msg },
            },
            response,
        } = error;
        if (response && msg) {
            showToast(msg, "toast toast-danger", "alert", true, getToastTimeLimit());
        } else {
            showToast("Internal server error!", "toast toast-danger", "alert", true, getToastTimeLimit());
        }
        showSpinner(false);
        throw error;
    }
}

The test file code which throws a error is
test("calling the api end point for a invalid input", async () => {
    const checkLoggedInSpy = jest
      .spyOn(http, "checkLoggedIn")
      .mockReturnValue(true);
    renderComponent();

    axios.post.mockRejectedValue({
      response: {
        data: {
          msg: "Invalid username or password",
        },
      },
    });

    const usernameInput = screen.getByPlaceholderText("Username");
    const passwordInput = screen.getByPlaceholderText("Password");
    fireEvent.change(usernameInput, { target: { value: "test" } });
    fireEvent.change(passwordInput, { target: { value: "test" } });

    await waitFor(() => {
      const loginButton = screen.getByTestId("login-btn");
      fireEvent.click(loginButton);

      expect(axios.post).toHaveBeenCalledWith(expect.any(String), {
        username: "test",
        password: "test",
      });
    });

    checkLoggedInSpy.mockRestore();
  });

I have tried with AI, but it is asking me to mock the function, but it suppose to run to increase the coverage
